# Transfer live video from an Android device

Tags: android

I want to access my android device (Nexus S) from my pc remotely. I was thinking of an application that would activate the camera and sent the video to my pc, something like Skype but without sound. My first thought was using a VPN connection, but it is a little bit restrictive as it is available only for API Level 14. I dont want to use a server cause I'll have to pay, unless I can avoid it.The concept is using the device for security like a wireless camera. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an app called [IpWebcam](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pas.webcam&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wYXMud2ViY2FtIl0.). It converts your phone into a wireless webcam. You may see the live video through browser or a player. Install it and you'll find the instructions inside :)

Comment: Thank you Waqas that was helpfull. Do u know how this app acctually works,e.g what classes is using etc cause I'd like to build sth on my own

Comment: Sorry, i'm not in its development team. You may ask its developer for further details. However, you may refer to (http://mjpeg.sourceforge.net/) and (http://code.google.com/p/mjpg-streamer-mini2440/) for tools which might be useful in its development

Comment: I'll try out the socket class, I think it should the trick. I think the IpWebcam is using the URLConnection class. Anyway thanks